# XMPP Chatroom client via AJAX?

Tags: jquery, ajax, xmpp

I'm using Openfire as an XMPP server, and it seems to be working great; the interface is also really nice.

Now I need a basic AJAX client so I can make a basic chat room (group chat) for a page.  I keep hearing about Strophe.js, but see NO examples on coding with it, and I also don't want to code something from scratch.

I'm looking for complete/premade projects.  I am also open to purchasing something, if need be.  I am NOT looking for a user->user chat, I want a group chat via XMPP.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Did you look at the dozen or more web-based clients at the official [XMPP site](http://xmpp.org/xmpp-software/clients/), to see if any of them meet your needs?

Comment: I have seen that.  If you looked at it, none of them are ajax-based.  They're all for mobile phones or Linux/Windows.

Comment: Then you didn't look very closely.  There are over a dozen AJAX web-based clients on that page.  Not to mention there are many that are not for mobile phones, Linux, or Windows (including the very first one on the list, which is only for Mac OS X)

Comment: I hadn't seen the "Show 10 entries", so it was showing only what I mentioned; I dropped it down, there are lots of browser-based items.  Currently looking into http://cgit.babelmonkeys.de/cgit.cgi/xmppchat/.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

http://professionalxmpp.com/ is a book I highly recommend. You will find very practical examples of Strophe library usage. I'm sure you will find the right solution in no time.